# Text along the planes in 3D

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, technical-drawing

I am not able to project correctly text along the planes in 3D. Complete code and picture is attached. The red text in xz plane at x = 0 $p_Y(y)$ and blue text in yz plane at y = 3 $p_X(x)$ are not along the planes i.e. not projected on planes.

kindly guide.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\newcommand\PrintFrac[2][3]{%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/frac,/pgf/number format/frac denom=#1}%
\pgfmathprintnumber{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
\begin{axis}
[   scale = 2,
    view={55}{30},
    ticklabel style = {font=\large},
    xlabel={\huge $X$}, 
    ylabel={\huge $Y$},
    zlabel={\huge $p_{XY}(x,y)$},
    zlabel style={rotate=0},
    xmin=0,xmax=3,
    xtick={0,1,2,3},
    ymin=0,ymax=3,
    ytick={0,1,2,3},
    zmin=0, zmax=0.9,
    ztick={0,0.4,0.8},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    xmajorgrids=true,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    zmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{m} \as \labela},
]
    \addplot3 [ycomb, ultra thick, scatter, mark = text,
              mark options={text mark=\PrintFrac{\labela},
                            text mark as node=true,
                            text mark style={scale=1.25, yshift=13pt}
                            }] table {
                            x   y   m 
                            1   1   0.33
                            2   1   0.33 
                            1   2   0.33 
                            };

\addplot3 [ycomb, ultra thick, scatter,color=red, mark = text,
              mark options={text mark=\PrintFrac{\labela},
                            text mark as node=true,
                            text mark style={scale=1.25, yshift=13pt}
                            }] table {
                            x   y   m
                            0   1   0.67
                            0   2   0.33
                            };

\addplot3 [ycomb,ultra thick, scatter,color=blue, mark = text,
              mark options={text mark=\PrintFrac{\labela},
                            text mark as node=true,
                            text mark style={scale=1.25, yshift=13pt}
                            }] table {
                            x   y   m
                            1   3   0.67
                            2   3   0.33
                            };

\node at (0,1.5,0.7) [red] {$p_Y(y)$};

\node at (2,3,0.7) [blue] {$p_X(x)$};

\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle this is rather easy. Load the `3d` library and add keys like `canvas is yz plane at x=0,` to the nodes and to the `text mark style`. The problem, though, is that pgfplots does additional scale transformations, which Ti*k*Z does not see. So we need to change the node scale factor, which you take to be `1.25`, to a smaller value. I also had to remove the `scale=2` in your plot in favor of setting some `width`, such that the `overfull hbox` warnings go away.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\newcommand\PrintFrac[2][3]{%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/frac,/pgf/number format/frac denom=#1}%
\pgfmathprintnumber{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.95\textwidth,
    view={55}{30},
    ticklabel style = {font=\large},
    xlabel={\large $X$}, 
    ylabel={\large $Y$},
    zlabel={\large $p_{XY}(x,y)$},
    zlabel style={rotate=0},
    xmin=0,xmax=3,
    xtick={0,1,2,3},
    ymin=0,ymax=3,
    ytick={0,1,2,3},
    zmin=0, zmax=0.9,
    ztick={0,0.4,0.8},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    xmajorgrids=true,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    zmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{m} \as \labela},
]
\addplot3 [ycomb, ultra thick, scatter, mark = text,
              mark options={text mark=\PrintFrac{\labela},
                            text mark as node=true,
                            text mark style={scale=1.25, yshift=13pt}
                            }] table {
                            x   y   m 
                            1   1   0.33
                            2   1   0.33 
                            1   2   0.33 
                            };
\addplot3 [ycomb, ultra thick, scatter,color=red, mark = text,
              mark options={text mark=\PrintFrac{\labela},
                            text mark as node=true,
                            text mark style={canvas is yz plane at x=0,
                            scale=0.2, yshift=13pt}
                            }] table {
                            x   y   m
                            0   1   0.67
                            0   2   0.33
                            };
\addplot3 [ycomb,ultra thick, scatter,color=blue, mark = text,
              mark options={text mark=\PrintFrac{\labela},
                            text mark as node=true,
                            text mark style={canvas is xz plane at y=0,
                            scale=0.2, yshift=13pt}
                            }] table {
                            x   y   m
                            1   3   0.67
                            2   3   0.33
                            };
\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0]
    \node at (1.5,0.7) [red,transform shape,scale=0.2] {$p_Y(y)$};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=3]
    \node at (2,0.7) [blue,transform shape,scale=0.2] {$p_X(x)$};
\end{scope}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you "angel" Schrondinger's Cat obliged.